# how to fire event for javascript changed input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-events

I have an simple `select` html element and im able to attach/fire the event `change`, and it is triggered when use changes manually, but when i change the value using the javascript. It doesnt fire the events. With some googling and research i realised, that `change` event is not triggerd for javascript changed values.

So, how do I track the events of value changes by javascript.? I know `propertychange` works for IE. but i want to track this in chrome. Any way to do that ?

Here is the code im using

```
<select id="state">
    <option>listening</option>
    <option>reading</option>
    <option>idle</option>
</select>
  // this code doesnt trigger event for javascript changed values in chrome
  $('#state').bind('propertychange change click keyup input paste', function(){
    var new_state = $(this).val();
    console.log("state changed to ", new_state);
});
```

Comment: The change event is not fired when the value is changed programatically - is the value changed by your own code or by some other library?

Comment: its changed by my own code.

Answer (score 0):

You can fire a javascript event by calling him. Like so :

```
$('btn').click(); // this will simulate a click
```

So you can do :

```
$('yourselector').change();
```

Or you can use [Trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) (slower) and do like this :

```
$('your selector').trigger( "change" );
```

Comment: i dont want to trigger change, i want to get the event when the value is changed..

Comment: There is no way to get this behaviour without using propertychange - and this event is only supported in IE. The answer given is correct.

Comment: @rrmerugu you can trigger this event when you wan't. This is the only way to trigger the event when value change